# Reducer cannot read property 'photos' of undefined? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, redux

Here is the initial state of my reducer, and I need to set it up in this way due to some post processing I need to do:

```
const initialState = {
  showAll: {
    photos: null
  }
}
```

Basically, I have a page where you see all your photos, and you can tag certain ones as your pinned photos.

Here's part of my reducer logic:

```
if (state.showAll.photos) {
    const showAllState = state.showAll.photos;
    showAllState.map(m => {
      if (action.payload.id === m.id) {
        m.pinned = true;
      }
    });
    showAllAfterPin = showAllState;
} else {
    showAllAfterPin = state.showAll.photos;
}
```

However, I get an error saying `cannot read property  'photos' of undefined` and I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What is there in `state` object? I think property `showAll` is not there. Try to debug

Answer (score 0):

Might be easier to just set your photos in `initialState` to empty array `[]` instead of `null`.

Another thing, your reducer should not mutate your state object.

Doing `const showAllState = state.showAll.photos` doesn't make it a new object.

Last thing, `showAllState.map(...)` needs to return an item inside the function body. It will create a new array.

Here's something you can do...

```
const { photos = [] } = state.showAll;
const updatedPhotos = photos.map(photo => {
   if (action.payload.id === photo.id) {
       return Object.assign({}, photo, { pinned: true })
   }
   return photo;
});    

// return entire state if this is inside your root reducer
return {
   ...state,
   showAll {
       ...state.showAll,
       photos: updatedPhotos
   }
}
```